# Change the size and specify a colour to one data point in autoplot Prcomp

Tags: r

I have plotted PC using autoplot and coloured it based on the species(~30 species). Of these I need to highlight only one selected species with different colour and size.

`autoplot(sample_pca, data = sample, colour = "species")`

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(ggfortify)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(tidyverse)

samples <-
  iris |>
  mutate(is_setosa = (Species == "setosa") |> ifelse("setosa", "other"))

iris |>
  select(-Species) |>
  prcomp() |>
  autoplot(data = samples, colour = "is_setosa", size = "is_setosa")
#> Warning: Using size for a discrete variable is not advised.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you.. in this case, instead of 'other' have to plot 29 species in different colour

Comment: According to your question, you want to highlight only one selected species with a different color. This is what I did with setosa in the example dataset.

Comment: For eg. 30 species is there in my dataset. I have to colour all 30 in different colours and highlight the species of interest with a specific colour and increased size